# LG monitor (24MK430H-B) shows "no signal" with RPi 4

Tags: monitor, ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi, lg

I've installed Ubuntu MATE with desktopify on a Raspberry Pi 4, got it running, used `disable_overscan=1`, all this in my LG TV.

Now I've moved the Pi to my office, bought an LG monitor (24MK430H-B) and it says that it has no signal. How can I get it working?

Comment: Do other devices work on the monitor using the same input & cable? Can you remove any changes from `config.txt`?

Comment: I can't use the same cable, i don't have any device with micro HDMI. But i plug it to my PS3 and the monitor worked fine. The Pi is running on other TVs with HDMI using the micro HDMI cable. There are no config.txt nor monitor.xml when i look for them on terminal.

Comment: `config.txt` etc should be in the `/boot` mounted partition

Comment: I've flashed the OS again. And tryed to boot it with de LG monitor. Didn't worked. Then i pulled the HDMI from the TV and out it on the monitor. And it was working with 1920x1080 rés. At 60H. But when i reboot, or shit ir down and try to Turn the pi on again it após detect the signal. If o remove what os writen in the boot/firmware/usercfg.txt then i can't even have imagem on the monitor.

Comment: Beyond what is available here (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) I'm not sure what's wrong. You could try setting `hdmi_group=1` and `hdmi_mode=16` to force 1920x1080 @ 60Hz if that worked after physically switching devices post startup. The monitors EDID information may be wrong or is being misinterpreted?